# Calling an in-line TVF with named parameters, what is the proper syntax?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I tried calling an in-line TVF with positional parameters and it works fine:

```
SELECT MyTable.Col1,
       (SELECT TvfColumn FROM ufnGetData(MyTable.Col1, MyTable.Col2)),
       MyTable.Col2
FROM MyTable
```

Then I tried to name the parameters to the TVF and it does not parse:

```
SELECT MyTable.Col1,
       (SELECT TvfColumn FROM ufnGetData(@Param1=MyTable.Col1, @Param2=MyTable.Col2)),
       MyTable.Col2
FROM MyTable
```

The function looks something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetData
(   
    @Param1 INT,
    @Param2 INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT 
       blah blah blah AS TvfColumn
)
GO
```

Giving an error similar to:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 23 Must declare the scalar variable
> "@Param2".
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24 Incorrect syntax near ','.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Table-Valued User-Defined Functions can't be treated like a Stored Procedure.  You don't use named parameters while calling them, it is position-based.  So in other words, what you are trying to do isn't possible.

Is there a reason why you want to use named parameters?  You need to have all parameters defined, so there is no real benefit that you would normally see with stored procedures.

Comment: The real benefit is that I can change parameter order in the TVF without affecting callers. It is also easier to see what the parameters are, if they are named, although I can get the same effect with well placed inline comments.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Sorry, it's not possible with SQL Server.

Comment: RE: "or any function". This is not true. Scalar UDFs can be invoked with `EXEC` and accept named parameters in that case.

Comment: "Is there a reason why you want to use named parameters? You need to have all parameters defined, so there is no real benefit"--in addition to the benefits cited by  @MichaelGoldshteyn and MartinSmith , the use of named parameters also makes it possible to exclude those that have a default value in a scalar UDF, i.e., you _don't_ need to have all parameters defined.

Comment: Naming parameters is a good practice to prevent bugs caused by omitting them, or by accidentally specifying them in the wrong order. The latter is particularly true if parameters are very similar, and thus easy to mix up.