# Using named parameters in Table Valued Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to use named parameters with table valued functions ? My users insist to use them with their interface to my db objects.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this? `select * from dbo.SomeFunction(@p = 1)` If so, the answer is that you can't, although I can't find any documentation that specifically says it. It would be interesting to know why they "insist", if they have some limitation with tools or other issues then I suggest you ask about that limitation and see if someone has an alternative. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219163/calling-an-in-line-tvf-with-named-parameters-what-is-the-proper-syntax) too.

Comment: The documentation has a sample of a parameter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Can you give an example of some code you've tried that does not work for you? If they simply want to see `@p = 1` somewhere in the code as @Pondlife suggested you could do `Exec sp_executeSQL 'Select * From dbo.SomeFunction(@p) As f', N'@p Int', @p = 1;`. It still doesn't put `@p = 1` in the function, but you can see `@p = 1` as the variable input at the end. Would this appease them?

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't do that. Unlike stored procedures where you can use named parameters the parameters in table valued functions are strictly position-based.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it has changed with SQL-Server 2016. Named parameter in T-SQL function is supported in SQL Server 2016 https://scribnasium.com/2017/01/named-parameters-in-t-sql-functions/

Comment: Solution in the article is not-so-good workaround. It works "properly" only for T-SQL functions which return scalar values, plus... It can affect performance.