# SQL Server : call function with parameter names

Tags: sql-server, function

Is there a way to call a SQL Server / T-SQL function using parameter names?

Something like:

```
select dbo.function1 (@par1 = 1, @par2 = 2)
```

It is possible to do so with stored procedures.

Comment: No, function parameters are position based<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219163/calling-an-in-line-tvf-with-named-parameters-what-is-the-proper-syntax

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no named arguments when calling functions I'm afraid. As you said before, there is in stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be possible only with EXEC statement:

```
EXEC @ret = dbo.function1 @par1 = 1, @par2 = 2
```

[See MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/execute-user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-ver16)