# SQL Passing arguments for a function by named parameters

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. I know that with stored procedures you can pass arguments by name.

```
EXEC PROC_A @p_para = 'Test'
```

Can one do the same with a function?

```
SET @iID = [dbo].[FUNC_GET_INTEGRITY_ID](@p_strSearchForValue = '805-2020', @p_strSearchForValue2 = DEFAULT, @p_tinProcessID = 1, @p_bitRunStatic = 1)
```

If this is not the correct syntax, what is it or is there another way to do this.

Would be nice to see the named parameters as a form of self documentation.

Comment: Found this that indicates it might never be coming :-) https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/361449/table-valued-udf-scalar-udf-functions-named-parameter-input

Comment: Have a look on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8219244/2451726)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct syntax for executing the function by named parameters (see Arulkumar's comment link above for details).

```
EXEC @iID = [dbo].[FUNC_GET_INTEGRITY_ID] @p_strSearchForValue = '805-2000', @p_strSearchForValue2 = DEFAULT, @p_tinProcessID = 1, @p_bitRunStatic = 1
```

Note that there are no brackets used as would be in a `SET` or `SELECT` statement.